# Boost::mutex - is it possible to lock it inside one class function and unlock on another?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex, boost-thread

So we have class with functions `a` and `b`. Thread `one` calls `a` and no other thread can call `a` or `b` untill `one` would call `b`. Meaning thread `one` would be capable to call `a` and than `a` and ... and than `a`, and while `one` had not called `b` other threads that want to call `a` or `b` stand waiting. is it possible to do such thing with `boost::mutex` and how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mutex is not a problem; it's the lock.  The simplest solution is
just to call `mutex::lock()` and `mutex::unlock()` manually, and forget
about the `mutex::scoped_lock`; after all, you don't want the lock to
respect scope.  The problem with this is the usual one; you probably
want to free the lock in case of an exception.  One solution would be to
allocate the `mutex::scoped_lock` dynamically, and use a `std::auto_ptr`
or a `boost::shared_ptr` to manage it.  (Curiously enough, neither
`boost::mutex::scoped_lock` nor `std::lock_guard` are movable, so you
need dynamic allocation in order to transfer ownership.)

Comment: how does a dynamically allocated mutex help if the thing that crashes the thread holding the mutex? After all the mutex is not *owned* by the thread, it's owned by the class?

Comment: It's not the `mutex` which you allocate dynamically, but the `scoped_lock`.  And you "manage" it like you would any other dynamic allocation.  (This does mean that you have to return it from the function which locks, and pass it into the function which frees.)

Comment: @James... aha... it would help to read the answer properly.. slow morning... :)

Comment: for new readers... auto_ptr is deprecated you prob wanna use unique_ptr

Answer (score 3):

It has separate `lock()` and `unlock()` functions. Make the mutex a member of your class, and then call these respective functions... I would find an alternative approach though - you could have all sorts of odd situations (say thread calling `a` crashes?)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it. Either you have your mutex as an attribute of a base class and then inherit your working objects from it. Or else send a reference of the mutex to each working class.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Just call `boost::mutex::lock()` from `a` and `boost::mutex::unlock()` from `b`.

But note that in the case of an exception thrown while the mutex is locked you should ensure that `unlock` is called eventually. And `scoped_lock` does that automatically, but you'll have to do it manually.